# In Cube I want to get average of a measure based on particular dimension and time period

Tags: mdx

In Cube I  want to get average of a measure  based on particular dimension and time period but it is returning the same result even if I apply sum, Avg or directly taking the measured value, Same Query if I run into SQL it returns 43 rows but in MDX query it returns only 1 row . as cube is aggregating the measure value    Query In SQL is As

```
 select Measure,[Dimension Name] from  datatable where dimension1key=1 and    countryKey=2 and regionKey=1 and channelKey=3  and timeperiod between(38,50) groupBy [Dimension Name],Measure
```

same in MDX if I write

```
select {[Measure].[price] } on columns,non empty({[Dimension].[Dimanesion Name]}) on rows from (select {[Dimcountry].[country Name].[asia]} on columns from (select {[Dimchannel].[channel Name].[a]} on columns from (select [dimension1].[Dimension1Key].[1]} on columns from (select {[region].[region Name].[abc]} on columns from retaoauditcube))))
```

it returns only one row  as aggregated value

Answer (score 1):

You may use the MDX AVG function:

```
With 
Member [Measure].[AVG Price] as
AVG(
    [Date].[Calendar].[Day].Members,
    [Measure].[Price]
)

Select 
{[Measure].[Price],[Measure].[AVG Price]} on 0,
Non Empty [Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Attribute].Members on 1
From [retaoauditcube]
Where ([Dimcountry].[country Name].[asia],[Dimchannel].[channel Name].[a],[dimension1].[Dimension1Key].[1],[region].[region Name].[abc])
```

Comment: I have tried Avg Also but as cube returns Aggregated values so its same as sum

Comment: Do you mean [Measure].[Price] = [Measure].[AVG Price]??

Comment: WITH MEMBER [Measures].[av. Price ] AS AVG(({[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].CurrentMember,{[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Year].[Year].Allmembers},{[dim Region].[Region Name].[Total id]}
,{[Dim Channel].[Channel Name].Children}),[Measures].[Price Per Pack]) select {[Measures].[av. Price ] } on columns,non empty{([Dim Flavor Category].[Flavor Category TD].[Flavor Category TD].ALLMEMBERS)} FROM ( SELECT { [Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51] } on columns FROM [dataCube])

Comment: Your code is so wrong. I doesn't work that way.  Please reuse my code above and read about AVG() function clearly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx

Comment: I have tried with set also and we are using a calculated measure in cube which is derived with formula Avg(price per pack)  that is also not working

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide any additional informations (the code, outputs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
With SET [ALL OTHERS] AS {   ({[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].& 51]:[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51]},[Measures].[Price Per Pack])}member [Measures].[AVG Price] as AVG([ALL OTHERS])  MEMBER [Measures].[Current AVG Price] AS MAX(({[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51]:[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51]}),[Measures].[Price Per Pack])MEMBER [Measures].[Sum Price] AS AVG(({[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51]:[Dim Timeperiod Derived].[Week Sequence].&[51]}),[Measures].[Price Per Pack]) SELECT {[Measures].[Current AVG Price ],[Measures].[Sum Price] ,[Measures].[AVG Price]} ON COLUMNS ,NON EMPTY {[Dim Flavor Category].[Flavor Category RD].[Flavor Category RD].ALLMEMBERS,[Dim Flavor Category].[Flavor Category RD].[ALL OTHERS]} ON ROWS FROM (SELECT {[Dim Product Level].[Product Level Name].[FLAVOUR]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Brand].[Brand Name].[COCA COLA]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Category].[Category Name].[SPARKLING]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Channel].[Channel Name].[Total Channel]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Subchannel].[Subchannel Name].[Total]} ON COLUMNS FROM (SELECT {[Dim Subregion].[Subregion Name].[Total]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Region].[Region TD].[Total ID]} ON COLUMNS  FROM (SELECT {[Dim Country].[Country Name].[Indonesia]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Smartscan ASEAN]))))))))
```

all these queries return the same output

```
      Current AVG Price              Sum Price         AVG Price
```

COLA    604314.177978516       604314.177978516     604314.177978516